# How search in doc file (word document) in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working in a project to preview a doc file and search on it. I successfully could open doc file using `QLPreviewController` but I don't know how to search for words or any thing in this file in iOS

Thanks

Comment: do you mean doc or docx files?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `convert doc or docx` file into `PDF` using [iOS-htmltopdf](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf)

Now there many `API` available for `PDF word searching functionality` such as [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten).

Hope its helpful in right direction........

Comment: Thanks prince, I know many frameworks can search in PDF but i ask for doc files

Comment: thats what i supposed to say that convert it to PDF and its well about to search words